# Graph theory: looking for a shortcut

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose I have a graph $G$ with $|V| = n$, and $G$ is not complete. Suppose further that I wish to find a set $V'$ of $m<n$ vertices such that the subgraph $G'$ induced by $V'$ has edge set $E'=\varnothing$. Is there a known theorem or algorithm besides brute force to help me find such a vertex set, or at least the existence or nonexistence thereof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [independent set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)) problem, and if you're looking for the largest such set within a graph, this is a hard problem and is NP-Complete.

However it is easy to find a maximal independent set: just take any vertex to begin with, and keep adding in independent vertices for as long as possible.

Comment: Perfect. For the specific problem I have, my values for $m$ and $n$ are fixed so I'm not looking for the largest $V'$, unless of course it ends up being less than $m$. Thanks!

Comment: Well, the problem "Does the graph $G$ have an independent set of size at least $m$" is NP-Complete, so don't expect a fast nice algorithm for it. However this problem is well-studied, and I'm sure there are many fast approximation algorithms and so on that will work for many practical applications.

Comment: Caught that, but you've answered my question and that's the main thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Bron–Kerbosch algorithm or another algorithm for finding cliques on each component of the complement of your graph.